# Is this air filter of poor quality?

Tags: air-filter

I just bought an air filter for my car(civic vti 1999).  Though it fits, It looks kind of cheap and not resembling the original filter in the car(which has a metal panel on the filter).  I was told motorquip is a good brand so I bought it with that in mind and it was £10 so I think that's standard for a replacement filter.  However just looking at the new filter makes me feel like it could be poor quality.

I have included a pic of the old filter(orange with silver panel) and new filter(black white).

Should I use the fact it doesn't resemble the original and lacking that metal part to suggest its of poor quality or is this something one cannot know just looking at the filters so the new one might be good?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to discern the quality of a filter material by a visual inspection. By looking at the filter you can't determine how fine a particle (measured in microns) the filter will trap. Even if the material appears courser visually it may be multi layered with a finer material protected by a course outerlayer. The filter may be designed with pleats in the media to increase the surface area which will increase service intervals. Without being privy to the technical specifications of the filter you don't know if you have a high quality filter media, but with only a few pleats that will clog quickly. It may contain a medium grade filter media but with a lot of pleats so it looks impressive. Your best option is to use brand name filters. Use those with a listed specification that it meets or exceeds the factory original filter.

Answer (score 0):

If it's shown as OEM fit for your car, it'll work. If you want the orange one with the metal guard on it, look for a Wix 46358 - most car spares places sell them.